# SVN+SSH Command not found on Mac Server

Tags: svn

I have just setup my mac server for SVN as listed here http://www.scottboms.com/2008/10/macsvnsshserver/

Everything went alright .... im fairly new at SVN so no doubt i have messed something up.

But when i run svn+ssh://USERNAME@IP_OR_HOSTNAME/test_proj from either my server or my workstation, i get the following error:

> svn+ssh: command not found

If anyone has any advice, that would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

svn+ssh is a protocol, not a program. You should run (for instance):

```
svn info --username USERNAME svn+ssh://HOSTNAME/path/to/repos/test_proj
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok .... It seems that my SSH pair didnt work ... although now it is, im still getting errors when im running the command you entered above.
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Only thing is i cant find the configuration file hahaha

Comment: It's in `~/.subversion/config`